Tips on proving that a set has an algebraic structure
If we read the article about ring on wikipedia, we can see that the properties of ring are as follows.

A ring is a set $R$ equipped with two binary operations $+$ (addition) and $⋅$ (multiplication) satisfying the following three sets of axioms, called the ring axioms:

$R$ is an abelian group under addition, meaning that:


$(a + b) + c = a + (b + c)$ for all $a, b, c$ in $R$ (that is, $+$ is associative).
$a + b = b + a$ for all $a, b$ in $R$ (that is, $+$ is commutative).
There is an element $0$ in $R$ such that $a + 0 = a$ for all $a$ in $R$ (that is, $0$ is the additive identity).
For each $a$ in $R$ there exists $−a$ in $R$ such that $a + (−a) = 0$ (that is, $−a$ is the additive inverse of $a$).


$R$ is a monoid under multiplication, meaning that:


$(a · b) · c = a · (b · c)$ for all $a, b, c$ in $R$ (that is, $⋅$ is associative).
There is an element $1$ in $R$ such that $a · 1 = a$ and $1 · a = a$ for all a in $R$ (that is, $1$ is the multiplicative identity).


Multiplication is distributive with respect to addition, meaning that:


$a · (b + c) = (a · b) + (a · c)$ for all $a, b, c$ in $R$ (left distributivity).
$(b + c) · a = (b · a) + (c · a)$ for all $a, b, c$ in $R$ (right distributivity).


And to check whether a set is a ring, we have to check one by one whether it satisfies the properties written above. And a typical example of a ring is the integer $\mathbb{Z}$. So I thought about an algorithm to check if something is a ring and practiced with $\mathbb{Z}$ to check the properties of rings. One of those results is shown below as an example.

If $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $(a + b) + c = a + (b + c)$.

I tried to prove that the set of integers $\mathbb {Z}$ is a ring for practice, but as above, I only got very vague results. Is there a way to avoid such vague results and get rigorous results in the process of proving that a set is a ring? I think that proving that a set has an algebraic structure such as a group, ring, or field in this way is too vague, so I would like to get help.
Edit: Of course, We can intuitively know that the integer system satisfies all the properties of the ring written above, but I think that proof is a task of thoroughly investigating the obvious, so I feel a little uncomfortable about just passing it on as if it satisfies these properties just because it is an integer. Is this the best proof that the set of integers is a ring?
And when proving that a set other than a number system has an algebraic structure such as a group, ring, or field, I have to prove that it satisfies the properties that each algebraic structure must have, but I am still immature, so it is difficult to prove. Can you give me some tips for proofs on general sets?

You have to use what you know about $\mathbb Z$. Either it is defined as a... ring (and it is done), or it is defined axiomatically. In which case, you have to derive/check the above properties using the axioms.

What "vague results" are you alluding to? What do you mean by "proving that a set has an algebraic structure such as a group, ring, or field in this way is too vague"? This is what is expected.

@AnneBauval The vague results I mentioned are, as I wrote in the question above, vaguely saying that if $\mathbb {Z}$ belongs to $a, b, c$ then $(a+b)+c = a+(b+c)$, which felt like circular reasoning, so I posted the question.

@MauroALLEGRANZA I'm really thanks for your comment! I will try it!

I did read what you wrote in the question above, and didn't (still don't) find anything "vague", whence my question. What you are quoting is one of the (precise) properties to check. Checking associativity of the addition on $\Bbb Z$ is not "circular". It must be derived from the definition of $(\Bbb Z,+)$.

@AnneBauval I think I misunderstood some things. Thank you for your comments.

HINT: To prove that addition on the integers is associative, consider using mathematical induction.

@PaulTanenbaum Hello, thank you so much for your comment. But is this what you mean by mathematical induction? I've been thinking about it, and in the case of associative, the formula is $(a · b) · c = a · (b · c)$. But so far, I've only proven mathematical induction when there is only one variable, such as when proving $1+2+3+ \cdots + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. So if I were to prove this case, when $a, b, c \in \mathbb{Z}$, I would have to prove $(a · b) · c = a · (b · c)$, so I would have to use mathematical induction for three variables,

@PaulTanenbaum but I've been thinking about it for a while, but I can't think of a good idea. It might be a hassle, but could you show me how to use mathematical induction only in the case of associative?

You don't have to do induction on each of $a$, $b$, and $c$. Think of a way you could do it in terms of a fourth value, $n$.
